# Rails network calls extremely slow from Sneakers worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabbitmq

I have a doozy of a problem right now and would be very happy with any ideas folks might have.

The problem:  Network calls are very slow (Redis, HTTP) when running in a Sneakers worker. For example, setting a key in redis is taking ~20 seconds, and an HTTP get call ~38 seconds.  From the `rails c` the same redis call takes < 1 second and the HTTP call about a second.

The set-up: Will try to be as concise as I can here.

- Everything is running in Docker (Rails + workers, Redis, Postgres etc..)
- Rails 4.2.7 is the main web app, using puma as as the web server
- There are two background jobs which are handled via Sneakers and triggered via RabbitMQ messages.  These "workers" include calls to classes inheriting from ActiveRecord which do the actual activities (i.e. make the HTTP call or interact with Redis)
- I have since simplified and only make a HTTP call within the Worker class (it does nothing else).  I have also moved it to the foreground for debugging.

Puma is configured to run in "single" mode (no workers, 1 thread).  Here is my current Sneakers configuration:

```
# config/initializers/02_sneakers.rb
  Sneakers.configure  daemonize: false,
                      amqp: "amqp://rabbitmq",
                      # log: "log/sneakers.log",
                      log: STDOUT,
                      pid_path: "tmp/pids/sneakers.pid",
                      threads: 2,
                      workers: 1,
                      durable: true,
                      vhost: '/',
                      exchange: 'exchange',
                      exchange_type: 'direct'

Sneakers.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
```

And my worker:

```
class StepWorker
  include Sneakers::Worker
  from_queue "queue", env: nil, timeout_job_after: 5.minutes, durable: true, ack: true

  def work(raw_event)
    logger.info { 'StepWorker received params: ' + raw_event }
    message = JSON.parse(raw_event)

    response = ""
    time = Benchmark.measure {
      response = RestClient.get('http://store/', { accept: :json })
    }
    logger.info { "response: #{response.length} in #{time.real}" }

    ack!
  end
end
```

I also have an [issue](https://github.com/jondot/sneakers/issues/256) going with some folks on the Sneakers.  Any ideas are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed a critical detail in the above question which leads to the source of the problem and rules out Sneakers.

The payload being sent is ~10MB, which rails can query in about 27ms but then takes 30 seconds to render as JSON and transfer (why it is so slow is another problem related to the conf / docker).

Redis is subsequently timing out as a consequence of the payload size (however 10MB throughput should not be so slow).

The timing issue (inability to reproduce) was due to the lack of disabling pagination on the testing of the HTTP.  Without pagination the size hits 10MB and things start to fall apart.

So, the answer here is that the problem is not related to Sneakers, however it was radically complicated because of it.  Removing Sneakers and running the commands directly would have been a much better starting point:

```
irb(main):002:0> time = Benchmark.measure {
irb(main):003:1*   response = RestClient.get('http://store?pagination=false', { accept: :json })
irb(main):004:1> }
=> #<Benchmark::Tms:0x00555f80bd3708 @label="", @real=39.22218326000075, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.0, @utime=0.030000000000000027, @total=0.030000000000000027>
irb(main):006:0> 
irb(main):007:0* time = Benchmark.measure {
irb(main):008:1*   StashService.set("cool", JSON.parse(response))
irb(main):009:1> }
Redis::TimeoutError: Connection timed out
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-3.3.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:111:in `rescue in _write_to_socket'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-3.3.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:104:in `_write_to_socket'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-3.3.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:131:in `block in write'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-3.3.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:130:in `loop'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-3.3.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:130:in `write'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-3.3.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:374:in `write'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-3.3.2/lib/redis/client.rb:271:in `block in write'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-3.3.2/lib/redis/client.rb:250:in `io'
...
4.2.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Just to add another piece of information.  My performance problem was resolved (knock on wood) by changing the following in `development.rb`: `config.assets.debug = false`